# Lightbox with HTML content covering whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are many many lightbox plugins.

What I am looking for is a lightbox plugin that supports HTML content and has a full page option(covering the whole body/page).

My HTML content in the lightbox won't cover the whole page but the box background should cover the whole page. I know I could do this myself but it's for a small project and doing everything by myself and optimizing the lightbox for responsive would be too much for that project.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [**fancyBox**](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) would be a good option for you. It's a highly extensible Lightbox alternative nthat supports HTML content, and even supports the ability to do full-page popups by specifying `100%` on the `width` and `height` parameters:

```
$.extend(this, {
  aspectRatio : false,
  type    : 'html',
  width   : '100%',
  height  : '100%',
  content : '<div class="fancybox-image">Full-screen</div>'
});
```

There's a demo page showcasing the functionality [**here**](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful), and in fact one of the examples showcases exactly what you are looking for [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2XhjG/).

Hope this helps! :)